# Mobile platform website has horizontal scrollbar, how do I remove it?

Tags: html, css

When I load my website homepage on a mobile device there is an ability to move the screen left and right, if I move it left it bounces back into place, but if I move it right it bounces back but will leave about 5px margin of white space throughout the entire webpage container except for the navbar. I have no content that is pushing the website width or margin-right. I am using bootstrap, i will upload a code snippet but the best way to see the issue is going to the website, it also only shows up on mobile devices, I don't have the problem when testing mobile view with google chrome mobile view. This problem only occurs on my homepage webpage, no other webpage has the problem. 
Website link: http://buildingims.com/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#0054a5" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#333">
 <title>Inspection Software for the Professional - Link Inspect Pro</title>
   
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico?v=3">

</head>

<body>
 <div id="ms-preload" class="ms-preload">
  <div id="status">
   <div class="spinner">
    <div class="dot1"></div>
    <div class="dot2"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="ms-site-container">
  <div class="modal modal-primary" id="ms-account-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog animated zoomIn animated-3x" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header d-block shadow-2dp no-pb">
      <button type="button" class="close d-inline pull-right mt-2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i> </span>
      </button>
      <div class="modal-title text-center">
       <a href="index.html">
        <img alt="The Best Home Inspection Software" src="assets/img/logo.png" style="height: 50px; width:350px;" />
       </a>
       <!-- <span class="ms-logo ms-logo-white ms-logo-sm mr-1">LIP</span> <h3 class="no-m ms-site-title">Link Inspect <span>Pro</span> </h3> -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-header-tabs">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-full nav-tabs-2 nav-tabs-primary" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
         <a href="#ms-login-tab" aria-controls="ms-login-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active withoutripple"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i> Login</a>
        </li>
        <!-- <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> <a href="#ms-register-tab" aria-controls="ms-register-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link withoutripple"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-add"></i> Register</a> </li>-->
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
         <a href="#ms-recovery-tab" aria-controls="ms-recovery-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link withoutripple"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-key"></i> Account Recovery</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="tab-content">
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active show" id="ms-login-tab">
        <form autocomplete="off">
         <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group label-floating">
           <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i> </span>
            <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-user">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="ms-form-user" class="form-control" required>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group label-floating">
           <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i> </span>
            <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-pass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="ms-form-pass" class="form-control" required>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mt-2">
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
              <input type="checkbox">Remember Me</label>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary pull-right">Login</button>
           </div>
          </div>
         </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div class="text-center">
        
        </div>
       </div>
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="ms-recovery-tab">
        <form>
         <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group label-floating">
           <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i> </span>
            <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-email-re">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="ms-form-email-re" class="form-control" required/>
           </div>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-raised btn-block btn-primary">Send Password</button>
         </fieldset>
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <header class="ms-header ms-header-primary">
   <div class="container container-full">
    <div class="ms-title">
     <a href="index.html">
      <img alt="Link Inspect Pro Best Inspection Software" src="assets/img/logo.png" style="height:45px; width:350px;" />
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
     
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-static ms-navbar ms-navbar-primary">
   <div class="container container-full">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="max-width:280px;">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img alt="The Best Inspection Software 2018" src="assets/img/logo.png" style="width:100%; height:70%; " />
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ms-navbar">
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="page-about.html" class="nav-link animated fadeIn animation-delay-7">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="page-features.html" class="nav-link animated fadeIn animation-delay-7">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle animated fadeIn animation-delay-7" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-name="blog">Industry <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i> </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="inspection-home.html">Home Inspection</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="inspection-compliance.html">Compliance Inspection</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="page-coming.html">Commercial Inspection</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="page-coming.html">Environmental Inspection</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="page-coming.html">Insurance Inspection</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="page-contact.html" class="nav-link animated fadeIn animation-delay-7">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link animated fadeIn animation-delay-7" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ms-account-modal"> Login </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="index.html#free-trial" class="btn btn-raised color-primary nav-link animated flipInX animation-delay-10" style="border-radius: 25px; height:65%;">Free Trial</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ms-toggle-left btn-navbar-menu"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-menu"></i>
    </a>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <header class="ms-hero-page ms-hero-img-keyboard ms-hero-bg-dark color-white">
   <div class="container index-1">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="text-uppercase typed-title">Inspection Software for the Professional <br><span class="color-primary typed-class"></span> </h1>
      <p class="lead lead-sm color-light">Link Inspect Pro is a cloud based, comprehensive software that allows you to perform inspections, create reports, and keep your company organized.</p>
      <ul class="ms-list-arrow">
       <li>High-Speed servers and performance.</li>
       <li>Comprehensive Software.</li>
       <li>Professional Reports.</li>
       <li>Perform Inspections.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <a href="page-login.html" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning">Sign Up for Free Trial</a>
      <a href="page-coming.html" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning pl-1 pr-1">Become a Network Inspector</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="text-center ms-margin">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-app" style="width:20%; min-width:200px">
      <div class="btn-container"> <i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> <span style="text-transform:uppercase;">Get it on</span>
       <br><strong>Google Play</strong>
      </div>
     </a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-app" style="width:20%; min-width:200px">
      <div class="btn-container"> <i class="fa fa-apple"></i> <span>Download on the </span>
       <br><strong>App Store</strong>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="container">

   <section>
    <h1 class="right-line">Features</h1>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="ms-icon-feature">
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-icon rotate-icon"> <span class="ms-icon ms-icon-lg ms-icon-inverse"> <a href="page-features.html" alt="Cloud"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i></a> </span>
       </div>
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-content">
        <h4 class="color-primary"><a href="page-features.html" alt="Cloud Computing">Cloud Hosting</a></h4>
        <p>Hosted on AWS, data is synced and stored through the cloud so you can access all your data on any device with any network at any location.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="ms-icon-feature">
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-icon rotate-icon"> <span class="ms-icon ms-icon-lg ms-icon-inverse"> <a href="page-features.html" alt="Reports"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i></a> </span>
       </div>
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-content">
        <h4 class="color-primary"><a href="page-features.html" alt="Professional Reports">Professional Reports</a></h4>
        <p>Sleek & Professional reports can be customized to ones own preference. As well as, delivere the report directly to the customer without ever leaving the site.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="ms-icon-feature">
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-icon rotate-icon"> <span class="ms-icon ms-icon-lg ms-icon-inverse"> <a href="page-features.html" alt="Apps"><i class="fa fa-tablet"></i></a> </span>
       </div>
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-content">
        <h4 class="color-primary"><a href="page-features.html" alt="Mobile Apps">Mobile and Tablet Apps</a></h4>
        <p>Link Inspect Pro apps for mobile devices allow seemless inspections to be done on site. Making inspections not only easy but quicker.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
     <h1 class="right-line">Inspections</h1>
     <div class="row">

     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-1">
      <div class="ms-icon-feature">
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-icon rotate-icon"> <span class="ms-icon ms-icon-lg ms-icon-inverse"> <a href="page-coming.html" alt="Shield"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i></a> </span>
       </div>
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-content">
        <h4 class="color-primary"><a href="page-coming.html" alt="Security Shield">Request Inspection</a></h4>
<p>Never lose any information again with lead and quote tNever lose any information again with lead and quote tNever lose any information again with lead and quote t</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-1">
      <div class="ms-icon-feature">
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-icon rotate-icon"> <span class="ms-icon ms-icon-lg ms-icon-inverse"> <a href="page-coming.html" alt="Organize"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a> </span>
       </div>
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-content">
        <h4 class="color-primary"><a href="page-coming.html" alt="Organization">Find an Inspector</a></h4>
        <p>Never lose any information again with lead and quoteNever lose any information again with lead and quote tNever lose any information again with lead and quote t.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="ms-icon-feature">
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-icon rotate-icon"> <span class="ms-icon ms-icon-lg ms-icon-inverse"> <a href="page-coming.html" alt="Customize"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a> </span>
       </div>
       <div class="ms-icon-feature-content">
        <h4 class="color-primary"><a href="page-coming.html" alt="Customization">Inspector Network</a></h4>
        <p>Create and edit templates, contract language, contactNever lose any information again with lead and quote tNever lose any information again with lead and quote t</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap wrap-mountain">
   <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center text-light mb-6">Inspection Software created with <strong>You</strong> in Mind</h2>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2 mb-4 center-block">
      <img src="assets/img/demo/mock.png" alt="Link Inspect Pro Best Inspection Software" class="img-fluid center-block" style="max-height:400px">
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1 pr-6">
      
      <div class="text-center"> <a href="page-features.html" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised mr-1"> Learn More about LIP <i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i> </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container mt-6 mb-1">
   <h2 class="text-center text-dark mb-6">Inspector Network</h2>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2 pr-6">
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1 mb-4 center-block">
     <img src="assets/img/demo/mock.png" alt="Link Inspect Pro Best Inspection Software" class="img-fluid center-block" style="max-height:400px">
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
  <style>
   .trial-block{background: url(assets/img/black_wall.png) no-repeat fixed; background-size: cover; background-position: center center !important; padding: 80px 0;}.trial-form-block{background: #fff; border-radius: 4px; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 600px; padding: 35px; width: 100%;}
  </style>
  <section id="free-trial">
   <div class="trial-block">
    <div class="trial-form-block">
     <div class="text-center">
      <h2>Link Inspect Pro Trial</h2>
      <p>Use Link Inspect Pro Software for 30 days or complete 3 inspections before subscribing</p>
     </div>
     <form action="https://linkinspectpro.com/users/registration" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="registration_form" id="registration_form">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" id="firstname" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" id="lastname" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
         <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" maxlegth="150" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="passconf">Confirm Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="passconf" value="" id="passconf" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="mobile_number">Phone Number</label>
         <input type="number" (keypress)="checkIfNumber($event)" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="mobile_number" value="" id="mobile_number" class="form-control" maxlength="12" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:1px">
         <select name="timezone" id="timezone" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-dropup-auto="false" required>
          
         </select>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:6px">
         <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-dropup-auto="false" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a Country</option>
          <option value="227">United States</option>
          <option value="39">Canada</option>
         </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="address1">Address 1</label>
         <input type="text" name="address1" value="" id="address1" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="address2">Address 2</label>
         <input type="text" name="address2" value="" id="address2" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
         <input type="text" name="city" value="" id="city" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:4px">
         <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-dropup-auto="false" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a State</option>
          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row label-floating">
         <label class="control-label" for="zipcode">Zipcode</label>
         <input type="text" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="zipcode" value="" id="zipcode" class="form-control" maxlength="10" required/>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      

      <div class="checkbox text-center" style="margin-top:20px;">
       
      </div>
      <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:19px;">
       <button name="mysubmit" type="submit" id="mysubmit" title="Start Trial" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised mr-1" value="submit">Start Trial</button>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section class="pricing-table">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-heading">
       <h1>Payment Plan</h1>
       <p>Subscribe for unlimited benefits.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
         <div class="price-table price-table-info center prominent">
        <div class="item">  <div class="ribbon">Subscribe</div>
      <header class="price-table-header">
       <h3> <sup>$</sup>30.00 <sub>/mo.</sub> </h3>
      </header></div>
      <div class="price-table-body">
       <ul class="price-table-list">
        <li>  Cloud hosting and synchronization.<i class="fas fa-check" style="float: right;"></i></li>
        <li>  3 free inspections included.<i class="fas fa-check" style="float: right;"></i></li>
        <li> Create custom inspection workflows.<i class="fas fa-check" style="float: right;"></i></li>
        <li>  2GB storage.<i class="fas fa-check" style="float: right;"></i></li>
        <li> Additional inspections only $10 each.<i class="fas fa-check" style="float: right;"></i></li>
       </ul>
       <div class="text-center">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-block btn-raised btn-warning">Buy now</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <aside class="ms-footbar">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 ms-footer-col">
     <div class="ms-footbar-block text-center">
      <div class="ms-footbar-block">
       <div class="ms-footbar-title">
        <ul class="list-inline">
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          |
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          <a href="page-about.html">About</a>
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          |
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          <a href="page-features.html">Features</a>
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          |
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          <a href="page-contact.html">Contact</a>
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          |
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          <a href="page-login.html">Login</a>
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          |
         </li>
         <li class="list-inline-item">
          <a href="index.html#free-trial">Register</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center text-md-center">
     <ul class="list-inline">
      <li class="list-inline-item">
       <a href="page-terms.html" target="blank" title="Terms of Use">Terms of Use</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
       |
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
       <a href="page-privacy.html" target="blank" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </aside>
  <footer class="ms-footer">
   <div class="container">
    <p>&copy; Copyright 2018. <br>All Rights Reserved by BIMS Corp</p>
   </div>
  </footer>
  <div class="btn-back-top">
   <a href="#" data-scroll id="back-top" class="btn-circle btn-circle-primary btn-circle-sm btn-circle-raised "> <i class="zmdi zmdi-long-arrow-up"></i>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="ms-slidebar sb-slidebar sb-left sb-style-overlay" id="ms-slidebar">
  <div class="sb-slidebar-container">
   <header class="ms-slidebar-header">
    <div class="ms-slidebar-login">
     <a href="page-login.html" class="withripple"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i> Login</a>
     <a href="index.html#free-trial" class="withripple"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-add"></i> Register</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-slidebar-title">
     <div class="ms-slidebar-t">
      <h3>Link Inspect <span>Pro</span> </h3>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>
   <ul class="ms-slidebar-menu" id="slidebar-menu" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <li>
     <a class="link" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="link" href="page-about.html">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="link" href="page-features.html">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card" role="tab" id="sch6">
     <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sc6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sc6">Industry</a>
     <ul id="sc6" class="card-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sch6" data-parent="#slidebar-menu">
      <li>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="inspection-home.html">Home Inspection</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="inspection-compliance.html">Compliance Inspection</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="page-coming.html">Commercial Inspection</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="page-coming.html">Environmental Inspection</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="page-coming.html">Insurance Inspection</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="link" href="page-contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="ms-slidebar-social ms-slidebar-block">
    <h4 class="ms-slidebar-block-title">Social Links</h4>
    <div class="ms-slidebar-social">
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @josh Yes, I actually have the same viewport meta tag on all my webpages but only the homepage is having the issue, not the others. I'm adding my homepage HTML code above.

Comment: @Josh the only fixed widths are for the Logo which is the same fixed width on every webpage. Its weird because nothing is near the border of the webpage container to push it out. Everything is within the borders.

Comment: I'll take a look later when I'm able to actually access your site. Sorry for stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @josh any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks for the advice.

Comment: You have a very nice site. I’m not able to reproduce this error, at least from Safari on my iPhone 6s. Same with Dolphin (cool cause of built-in ad blocking for mobile). Could you try to reduce this to an [MCVE]?

Comment: @Josh Thank you,w hen you say you can't reproduce this error, does that mean your not having any issue with the site, it works fine? I have an older mobile device (iPhone 5) so maybe it just happens with the outdated software. Also, I'm not sure I'll be able to make a minimal example, I would need to minify the CSS and JS files, which are both extremely large files. It seems no one else is having this issue so maybe its something I don't need to worry about.

Comment: It appears so. If you're still worried about it, you can run it on some different emulations of mobile browsers: [Opera Mobile Emulator](https://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator) is one I like to use. Works for any of the main operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a padding of `35px` on the class `.trial-form-block`, you have to take care of it on mobile screens with smaller values using media queries.

Comment: thank you for response, I removed the padding completely to see if it would work, but I'm still having the issue.

Comment: @Max do you still have the issue, i don't see any horizontal scroll bar on your website now

Comment: yes still having issue. Are you viewing it on a mobile device? If so what browser do you use?